# Qt: write HTML-String in XML-File

Tags: html, string, qt, escaping

I have a HTML-Text that I get from a textEdit and save it into a QString. Then I want to write the String into a XML-File but every time I write it, it automatically escapes the special characters like `", <> and &`.So, when I read the file with a second program and try to set the text to another `textEdit`, it just sets the text, but doesn't recognize it as a HTML.

Is there any option to write a `QString` without escaping or can I revert the escaping when reading the text from the XML-File?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Could you show some code ?

Comment: How are you writing to the XML file etc, having some code would help clarify this issue.